# Javascript center div on the page include scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html

In javascript I need to show div content on the center of the browser window; Content of the window is high therefore it has a scroll.

How can I set up div element on the center of the screen independently of the scroll ?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want a div overlay that remains fixed when you scroll the page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this CSS (You don't need javascript for that):

```
#divID{
  width:500px;   /* adjust */
  height:500px;  /* adjust */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -250px;  /* half of the width */
  margin-top: -250px;  /* half of the height */
  position:fixed;
}
```

### [You can check out the demo here including scrolling](http://jsbin.com/ikuwe4)

You can make the div pretty with additional CSS.

### [Check out demo](http://jsbin.com/ikuwe4/2)

Comment: This works great, unless the size of the browser view is less than 500px (or whatever), at which point it gets pushed off the top of the window. Is Javascript still needed to make sure the top of the div remains in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You want a CSS property, not JS. What you need to make it scroll is `overflow:scroll;`. Add that to the CSS used on the box.